# Qt program crashes on QPainter::drawPixmap()

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5

I am having problem where my Qt program crashes after calling `QPainter::drawPixmap()`. I have spent 2 days debugging this and have decided that I must be unintentionally abusing some feature of Qt.

[A working example of this problem can be found here](https://github.com/kyle7119/stackoverflow_question).

My code consists of a QML file that updates the following properteries:

```
Q_PROPERTY(qreal longitude READ getLongitude WRITE setLongitude NOTIFY latitudeChanged)
Q_PROPERTY(qreal latitude READ getLatitude WRITE setLatitude NOTIFY latitudeChanged)

void Map::setLongitude(qreal longitude)
{
    double diff = (this->longitude - this->pixmapCenter.longitude()) * scale;
    this->longitude = longitude;

    if (qFabs(diff) > 50)
    {
        MapTile result = updatePixmap(scale, longitude, latitude);
        pixmap = result.pixmap;
        pixmapCenter = result.center;
    }
    update();
}

void Map::setLatitude(qreal latitude)
{
    this->latitude = latitude;
}
```

That in turn regenerates a new Pixmap

```
MapTile updatePixmap(double scale, double longitude, double latitude)
{

    QPixmap myPixmap(800, 400);
    myPixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
    QPainter painter(&myPixmap);
    painter.translate(400, 240);
    QPen pen;

    pen.setColor(Qt::white);
    pen.setWidth(1);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    QRectF boundaries(QPointF(-91.55 , 41.55) * scale,
                     QPointF(-91.45, 41.45) * scale);
    boundaries.translate(-longitude * scale, -latitude * scale);
    painter.drawRect(boundaries);
    painter.end();

    QGeoCoordinate center(latitude, longitude);
    return MapTile(myPixmap, center);
}
```

This new pixmap is then drawn on the screen at the appropriate location. It is important to note that the program runs fine for a few seconds before it crashes.

It crashes with a segfault error in qdrawhelper_sse2.cpp line 587.

```
void Map::paint(QPainter *painter)
{
    painter->translate(boundingRect().width()/2, boundingRect().height()/2);
    painter->scale(1, -1);

    painter->translate((pixmapCenter.longitude() - longitude) * scale,
                       (pixmapCenter.latitude() - latitude) * scale);
    QPoint corner(-pixmap.width()/2, -pixmap.height()/2);

    painter->drawPixmap(corner, this->pixmap);

}
```

Here is an image of the moment of the crash

[image]

Comment: At what moment crashes ?, I'm trying it and it works, it shows a moving square.

Comment: What version of Qt do you have, what is your compiler?

Comment: 5.9.3 / mingw53_32

Comment: You have executed it in debug or release mode. It works for me correctly in Linux with Qt 5.10

Comment: I am running on Window 7. Both debug and release mode fail, but release is more consistent.

Comment: This seems to me to be a bug, I recommend reporting it to Qt by pointing to the version of your graphics card and the drivers. What is your graphic card?

Comment: I have reproduced it across several computer with various discrete and dedicated graphics cards

Comment: Then it's a bug, report it :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Qt 5.9 and 5.10. See [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65387).